# FolderClosedIOException while reading mail with Java Mail for attachment > 10MB

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

This is happening for the emails having attachment > 10Mb. We are trying to download the attachment and saving it on local. We are getting below error after processing  3/4 mails.
We are using *Java.Mail.1.3.2* to write the data in file byte by byte.

```
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.FolderClosedIOException
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.forceCheckExpunged(IMAPInputStream.java:100)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.fill(IMAPInputStream.java:150)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.read(IMAPInputStream.java:208)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.read(IMAPInputStream.java:234)
        at com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream.getByte(BASE64DecoderStream.java:358)
        at com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream.decode(BASE64DecoderStream.java:249)
        at com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream.read(BASE64DecoderStream.java:144)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
```

Comment: First, if possible at all, you should use the latest JavaMail version (1.6.5, and it is named JakartaMail now).
Next we need to know the make of the MailBox server – do you connect to Office365?
If so, it might be that you hit one of the issues coming with that product …

Comment: We are not considering the upgrade option as of now since the application is a legacy application. We are definitely connecting to Office 365. But processing get stuck after downloading 4/5 mail attachment of > 10mb

Comment: Did you set `mail.imap.partialfetch` to true (that is the default, so it is true if you do not set it at all), and what is the value for `mail.imap.fetchsize` (only relevant if partialfetch is true; default is 16kB)? Try partialfetch = true and fetchsize = 5MB (or higher) if your settings are different. See https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html